# How to Add products to cart when clicks on a custom button

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, payment, onestepcheckout

I need single click checkout of product when user clicks on a custom button in my custom controller. Hope will get help.

Answer (score 1):

You can add button though standard catalog page. "Object manager" will get the functionality.

Here is the code for button:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');


<div class="product-item-inner">
                                <div class="product actions product-item-actions"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions') ? $position : '' ?>>
                                    <div class="actions-primary"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ? $position : '' ?>>
                                        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                            <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                            <form data-role="tocart-form" data-product-sku="<?=  /* @NoEscape */ $_product->getSku() ?>" action="<?= /* @NoEscape */ $postParams['action'] ?>" method="post">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postParams['data']['product'] ?>">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED] ?>">
                                                <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                                <button type="submit"
                                                        title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                                                        class="action tocart primary">
                                                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                </button>
                                            </form>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
                                                <div class="stock available"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                            <?php else: ?>
                                                <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary') ? $position : '' ?>>
                                        <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')): ?>
                                            <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_product)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php if ($showDescription):?>
                                    <div class="product description product-item-description">
                                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                                        <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_productNameStripped ?>"
                                           class="action more"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Learn More') ?></a>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
```

**Here "$_product" is the product collection array.**

Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need to add the specific product to the cart and redirect to checkout page directly. I added this code to my template but no effect